# mysql insert max min value grouped by date

Tags: mysql, sql, select, insert-into

This is my table schema:

```
mysql> describe stocks;
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id        | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| symbol    | varchar(32) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| date      | datetime    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| value     | float(10,3) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| contracts | int(8)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| open      | float(10,3) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| close     | float(10,3) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| high      | float(10,3) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| low       | float(10,3) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
9 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I added two new columns named high and low so they are empty now.

**My goal is fill up these columns with the relative max(value),min(value) based on each daytime!**

My first insight is this query:

```
select distinct DATE(date),max(value) as max,min(value) as min from stocks GROUP BY DATE(date);

...

| 2017-02-20 | 19130.000 | 18875.000 |
| 2017-02-21 | 19170.000 | 18780.000 |
| 2017-02-22 | 19125.000 | 18745.000 |
| 2017-02-23 | 18980.000 | 18765.000 |
| 2017-02-24 | 18840.000 | 18505.000 |
+------------+-----------+-----------+
```

that achieve the first step, now I should join these results with each rows:

```
| 900363 | FIB7C  | 2017-02-20 17:49:44 | 18930.000 |         1 | 0.000 | 0.000 | 0.000 | 0.000 |
```

and insert the correct value based on DATE(date)  but I still not catch to do with INSERT INTO.
Thanks for helps regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a `join` in the `update` along with an aggregation to calculate the values:

```
update stocks s join
       (select date(date) as d, max(value) as dhigh, min(value) as dlow
        from stocks s
        group by date(date)
       ) sd
       on date(s.date) = sd.d
    set s.high = sd.dhigh, 
        s.low = sd.dlow;
```

Comment: Thanks a lots, It works perfectly. I only modify join match -> DATE(s.date) = sd.d.